# How to Insert Image in crystal report using asp.net C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I have here a problem about dynamically passing an image(s). ~/1.jpg or ~/2.jpg. Someone hit's a button and crystal report will be displayed, is it possible to display the picture in a datacolumn byte[]? or what would be the best thing to do with this one. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can display a picture in a datacolumn of a byte array, you can transform it using many ways, like this for example:

```
public byte[] SaveImage(BitmapSource bitmap)
{
    using (MemoryStream MS = new MemoryStream())
    {
        BmpBitmapEncoder Encoder = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
        Encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmap));
        Encoder.Save(MS);

        return MS.GetBuffer();
    }
}
```